# Failure of the Pumping Lemma

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

On the Wikipedia page for the Pumping Lemma for Context-Free Languages, a language, 
$$
\{b^j c^k d^l | j, k, l \in N\} \cup \{a^i b^j c^k d^l | i > 0, j = k = l\}
$$
is introduced. The pumping lemma proof for this supposedly fails because, given a string without *a*'s, you can pump the *b*'s and, given a string with *a*'s, you can pump the *a*'s.  In either case, all of the possible cuttings are pumpable according to the constraints of the language.

For example, given the string
$$
a^k b^k c^k d^k
$$
you can split *vwx* over *|a|* and pump, leaving *|b|* = *|c|* = *|d|*.

Why can the string
$$
a b^k c^k d^k
$$
not be used?

This seems to meet all the constraints of the pumping lemma, and you cannot split *vwx* across *|a|*.  If *v* = *a* then *x* must contain at least one *b*.  The string cannot be pumped for any *i* > 2 as the *|b|* will exceed the length of *|c|* **and** *|b|* will exceed the length of *|d|*.

Is there some reason that *|a|* > 1 or *|a|* = *k*?

Comment: I realize that this example as well as { a^i b^j c^k | i = j or j = k but not both } are commonly used to transition into a discussion of Ogden's Lemma.  I am curious as to why the above string cannot be used to show the language is not context-free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition of the Pumping lemma is fulfilled for words of the form $ab^kc^kd^k$.

Pick $v=a$, $u=x = \varepsilon$, and $w$, $y$ arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought that neither v or x could be empty, but one of them can be.